# TeXMaker compilation error, Font OT1/ptm/bx/n/20.74=ptmb7t at 20.74pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts, errors

when I am compiling any TeX document in my TeXMaker, it is giving me the following error message.

`Font OT1/ptm/bx/n/20.74=ptmb7t at 20.74pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
 found.`

I am using Linux.

Comment: Which TeX distribution are you using, and which program (XeTeX, LuaTeX, etc.)?

Comment: use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` before you load the Times font.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to work the font times. Related to the [font catalog](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/times/) your have to load the following packages:

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

The German document `l2tabu` recommends:

```
￼\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

After this update you it should work.

Comment: `￼\usepackage{mathptmx}` solves the issue for me as well.